# Share FireFox's Session Manager sessions

Tags: firefox, dropbox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, session-manager

I use FireFox at home and at work. I'm able to use DropBox on both.

I wanted to share a FireFox's Session Manager session on them, so that pages I leave open at home will be available next day at work, and vice-versa.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Do you always close FF when you aren't using it?\

Comment: Sure;  Use syncing software to sync your profile to a folder to a folder that exists in your DropBox folder.

Comment: I don't close either of them. But I can manually load a session file if needed, I just don't wanna risk forgetting of manually saving it.

Comment: I think it won't work synching the whole profile. Will FireFox notice a file was changed and reload it?